# Import pdf into Excel - NOT convert

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I would like to import Legal and Professional Invoices into my Excel workbook so that an auditor will not have to receive additional emails that would normally include about 50 invoice copies. I can import pdf as object, one page at a time, but the file gets too large. Importing as a picture requires too much photo editing. Is there a way to import a multi page pdf into Excel that does not make the file excessively large?

Comment: First question: what led you to believe embedding a PDF into a spreadsheet is the best way? There are utilities that can merge multiple PDF files into a single PDF, which would accomplish the exact same thing without messing with Excel. Would that do what you need?

Comment: No, that does not do what I need. I understand what you are saying by consolidating the pdf's, but I also need them to go into the Excel as backup to other data in the Workbook without making the file size too large.

Comment: You'll have this issue so long as you insist on embedding the PDF into the spreadsheet. Does the auditor have a system that only accepts spreadsheets?

Comment: No, I was just trying to have everything in one file, analysis and backup. This was not a do or die project. I was just wondering if I was missing something, apparently not. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: You're welcome. The general rule of thumb is that unless absolutely necessary, files should contain only the sorts of information they are designed for. They may be capable of holding other types of information, but there may be issues such as the ones you've experienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to embed files and other things into Excel spreadsheets, this should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Excel spreadsheets are designed to handle numbers and some letters most efficiently.

When you place something else, for instance a PDF, into a PDF by embedding, or even by screenshot (which creates a picture, which is also not numbers or letters), that the spreadsheet is not designed to handle, it may be CAPABLE of handling the content, but it will not be as effective or efficient in doing so.

The file sizes will likely balloon, and there could also be compatibility issues in certain circumstances.

The best thing to do is to keep each file in its own appropriate type.